# my smartwatch optical sensor does not turn on when I request the heart rate in a mobile app

Tags: android, mobile, gatt, wearables

I found this code in github that can get the heart rate from a smartwatch through a gatt conection on bluetooth. The heart rate seems right, but i have to make the smartwatch turn on the green led, measuring my heart rate in the watch app. I expected to be able to control the activation of this green led from the mobile app. is there any possible way?

the code:

https://github.com/4z7l/Android-BLE-Connect

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the smartwatch. An ordinary dedicated Bluetooth heart rate monitor simply has on/off states via a power button.

Comment: Its written [here](https://github.com/4z7l/Android-BLE-Connect#preview) that it can only get the value of wearable device.